# Grant users access to all external buckets but exclude our own account buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to give IAM users access to ALL external buckets- buckets not in our own account.

For example, publicly accessible buckets or buckets someone gives our AWS account access to. If the IAM user in our account does not have access to an external bucket (via IAM policy) they can't access it.

I can't grant them access to ALL buckets though because that will include our own buckets - which we don't want some users to access, or only give access with specific permissions.

Essentially I want a condition that says:

```
IF NOT <MY AWS ACCOUNT> 
    grant s3:*
ELSE
    don't modify existing S3 permissions
```

I want to have a policy I can just apply to users or roles that allow access to all external buckets.

### Edit

Looks like you can use `aws:ResourceAccount`?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_resource_account_data_exch.html

Comment: I don't think this is possible because Amazon S3 ARNs do not refer to an account number. Also, [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon S3 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html) does not list an Account ID as an available condition.

Comment: What is your particular use-case for requiring this? I could understand wanting to provide credentials to a user for accessing 3rd-party buckets (eg with shared data) but not wanting to grant access to buckets in the same account (for security/privacy reasons). However, it is necessary to grant `s3:*`-like permissions to be able to access external buckets. These do seem like conflicting requirements when it comes to granting access.

Comment: I dont care what access they have to other parties buckets, they can break those. I dont want to give them access to upload/delete/etc our accounts buckets. is checking if the bucket prefix doesnt match my companies prefix (assuming all my buckets use the same prefix) and then allowing s3:* the only way to do something like this?

Comment: An interesting conundrum! The only way I can immediately think to do this would be to create a separate AWS Account (that has no buckets) and allow them to assume an IAM Role in that account. They could then be granted lots of S3 permissions without granting access to sensitive buckets.

Comment: Are you trying same account or cross-account access?

Comment: This might help you: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/

Answer (score 0):

As you alluded to in the edit, you can use the below policy to allow an IAM role access to S3 resources in accounts other than your own.

You may use this if you expect other accounts to use [resource based permissions to allow your role access to their s3 resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies-cross-account-resource-access.html#access_policies-cross-account-delegating-resource-based-policies), but you don't want to give your role access to all of s3 in your own account.

> ***Note***: replace `111111111111` with your account id

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": ""
        },
        {
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceAccount": "111111111111"
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a condition to the policy: [IAM JSON Policy Elements: Condition Operators - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html)

Edit:
Based on the conversation and further research, this won't work for IAM users. You might be able to add a `DENY` policy to each of your buckets based on the `aws:PrincipalTag` and tag any user that you don't want to have access.

Comment: What condition would that be? I can't immediately think of something that would refer to the account of an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: yes this is my problem I cant find a condition. the best I could find was s3:prefix but that would mean all my buckets would need to have the same prefix. What is the best practice for my use case?

Comment: You're right. I was thinking about some of the conditions like `aws:SourceAccount`, but that has limited use, and wouldn't work in this case.